# How to pass bytes(ArrayBuffer) between python & js in frida?

Tags: ios, frida

javascript code:

```js
    rpc.exports = {
        something: function (data, size) {
            // data maybe ArrayBuffer
        }
    }
```

python code:

```py
zip = gzip.compress(json.dumps(info).encode('utf8')) # zip -> bytes
script.exports.something(zip, len(zip))
```

According to frida's document, JavaScript can pass byte arrays to python through the `send` method, so is there any way to pass byte arrays from python to JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question

python

```py
script.exports.something([0x33, 0x34, 0x35], 3)
```

js

```js
    rpc.exports = {
        something: function (data, size) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data), size);
            // output: [51,52,53] 3
        }
    }
```

More complicated example that hopefully will answer future questions;

python side:

```py
def on_message(msg, data):
  if msg['payload'] == 'tag1':
    print('bytes from js:', data)
    # sending bytes to js
    script.post({'type': 'tag2', 'payload': list([0x33, 0x34, 0x35])})
```

javascript side:

```js
  // send bytes to python
  send("tag1", ptr(0x1234).readByteArray(64));
  recv('tag2', function (value) {
    var data = value.payload;
    console.log('received bytes from python:', data, 'size:', data.length);
  })
  .wait(); // block until python respond
```